# Minimal options for Qt configure script

Tags: qt, qt5, qmake

I want to know the minimal options I need to pass to the qt configure script for a successful configure. If I do not pass any argument, the configure will fail.

```
c:\build>c:\Qt5.12.1\5.12.1\Src\configure.bat
+ cd qtbase
+ c:\Qt5.12.1\5.12.1\Src\qtbase\configure.bat -top-level
Bootstrapping qmake ...
mingw32-make: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
c:\build\qtbase>cd "c:\build"

c:\build>"c:\build\qtbase\bin\qmake.exe" "c:\Qt5.12.1\5.12.1\Src" --
c:/Qt5.12.1/5.12.1/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/resolve_config.prf:25: 'addExclusiveBuilds' is not a recognized test function.
c:/Qt5.12.1/5.12.1/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/resolve_config.prf:37: 'addExclusiveBuilds' is not a recognized test function.
Unknown generator specified: DUMMY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimal configure options for a sucessfull build is no options. Try to follow the steps describing the building steps in [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/windows-building.html) (this page describe native win build and mingw too).